# Proguard find classes which does not exist

Tags: java, proguard

I want to user **proguard** to pack my jar files. One of the dependency is named *jersey* which is pulled in by 3rd party library. I am sure this *jersey* library is available on the machine I intended to deploy my jar, so I decided to remove it from my package.

- I removed any jars which name contains **jersey** from the `-injars` option
- I added the library to `-libraries` option *I think proguard will still need it*

After I ran proguard, I got this error

> [error] Warning: library class
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener$AnnotatedClassVisitor
>   extends or implements program class org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor

I added `-dontwarn com.sun.jersey.**` to my proguard configuration, and get rid of that error. Then I open my jar, I cannot find any class which has a name similar to the one in the error message.

**I think proguard will only report issue from the `-injars` libraries, or I am wrong?**

If I indeed wrong. What's the point to complain about issues in the `-libraries`? You can't fix it any way.

Comment: Finding something that does not exist is an interesting idea.  Impossible, but interesting :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the documentation says:

> -injars class_path
>
> Specifies the input jars (or aars, wars, ears, zips, apks, or directories) of the application to be processed. The class files in these jars will be processed and written to the output jars. ...
>
> -libraryjars class_path
>
> Specifies the library jars (or aars, wars, ears, zips, apks, or directories) of the application to be processed. The files in these jars will not be included in the output jars. **The specified library jars should at least contain the class files that are extended by application class files.**  ...

---

> I think proguard will only report issue from the -injars libraries, or I am wrong?

That is not entirely correct.  Certainly, that is not what you are observing.  The implication of that error message is that the "extends" rule applies to classes in the -libraryjars libraries ... at least in some circumstances.

(It would make sense.  Suppose A was an application class, and L1 & L2 are library classes.  If A extends L1 extends L2, then proguard needs both L1 and L2 to analyse the type hierarchy of A.)

I think that the correct fix in this case is to add the "asm" JAR to the `-libraryjars` list.  The JAR will be required at runtime by jersey, and you are supposed to add all such JARs to the `-libraryjars` list.